# Which notation is correct/preferred for the squared form of the function: $ f_a(x)^2 $ or $f^2_a(x) $?

Tags: notation

I have a function $f_a(x)$ with one independent variable $x$ and a parameter $a$; if I want to write the square form of this, which one is correct or preferred?

$$  f_a(x)^2 \qquad \text{or} \qquad  f^2_a(x) $$

Comment: Best and clearest in my opinion is $(f_a(x))^2$. Sometimes $f_a^2(x)$ can mean different things, depending on the context, such as the second derivative of $f_a$ wrt x, or the function composition $f_a(f_a(x)) $.

Comment: I use the second for trig functions, otherwise, I clear ambiguity by using brackets: $[f_a (x)]^2.$